# Как найти расхождение значений в одном массиве?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть один массив session, внутри этого массива session имеются ключи и соответствующие этим ключам массивы,

Вопрос как в массиве session найти расхождение значений?

Comment: Уточните, что здесь будет «расхождением»:   `$session = [
  'a' => ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  'b' => ['A', 'B', 'CCCP'],
  'c' => ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  'd' => ['A', 'BBBB', 'C'],
 ];`

Comment: Значит из ключа а нужно вывести С из ключа b CCCP далее ключ 'с' значение  С расходится в сравнении с ключом 'b' а поэтому это нужно на вывод и остаётся ключ d расходится значение BBBB в сравнении с предыдущим значением из ключа 'с' Это реально сделать? Ведь нужно следить за историей изменений данных

Comment: Т.е. считать `$session` сортированным, и сравнивать только поочередно с соседями? Напр. различия между "a" и "d" уже никому не интересны?

Comment: Да да хотя бы так, этого мне будет достаточно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После уточняющих комментариев нарисовалась совсем другая картина. Сравниваем только текущий со следующим. И, т.к. нужна разница с обеих сторон, то сортируем оба, и двигаемся по одному, сравнивая:

```
<?php

$session = [
    'a' => ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'b' => ['A', 'B', 'CCCP'],
    'c' => ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'd' => ['A', 'BBBB', 'C'],
];

$result = [];
$keys = array_keys($session);
for( $i = 0; $i < count($keys)-1; $i++) {

    $A = $session[ $keys[ $i]];
    $B = $session[ $keys[ $i+1]];

    printf( "%d  [%s]  [%s]\n", $i, implode(',', $A), implode( ',', $B));

    sort( $A);
    sort( $B);

    for( $ai=0, $bi=0; $ai < count($A) && $bi < count($B); $ai++, $bi++) {

        if( $A[$ai] === $B[$bi]) {
            continue;
        } else if( $A[$ai] < $B[$bi]) {
            $bi--;
            echo "A not in B: " . $A[$ai] . PHP_EOL;
        } else if( $A[$ai] > $B[$bi]) {
            $ai--;
            echo "B not in A: " . $B[$bi] . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    if( $ai < count($A)) {
        echo "A not in B: " . implode(',', array_slice( $A, $ai)) . PHP_EOL;
    } else if( $bi < count($B)) {
        echo "B not in A: " . implode(',', array_slice( $B, $bi)) . PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo '------' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

На выходе:

```
0  [A,B,C]  [A,B,CCCP]
A not in B: C
B not in A: CCCP
------
1  [A,B,CCCP]  [A,B,C]
B not in A: C
A not in B: CCCP
------
2  [A,B,C]  [A,BBBB,C]
A not in B: B
B not in A: BBBB
------
```

Comment: Спасибо, с комментариями выше я всё ближе к выполнению задачи, но ещё совсем не то. Представьте что имеются архивные данные и с помощью вопроса в заголовке темы нужно Найти расхождение то есть менявшиеся данные

Answer (score 1):

Есть встроенная [функция](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php).

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
foreach($_SESSION as $el1)
    foreach($_SESSION as $el2)
    {
        print_r(array_diff($el1, $el2));
    }
```

Comment: Вот вы и Попались, мне нужно в ОДНОМ массиве проверить на расхождение, а у вас array1 и array2

Comment: а что Вам мешает пройтись двумя циклами по ОДНОМУ массиву, чтобы попарно сравнивать элементы?

Comment: `foreach..foreach` – так выполняется `(n^2+n)/2` лишних проверок: каждая пара сравнивается дважды + каждый массив сравнивается однажды сам с собой.